# Python program to read a excel sheet does not work?

Tags: python, xlrd

I tried this code from [javatpoint.com](https://www.javatpoint.com/python-read-excel-file)

Code

```
   # Import the xlrd module    
import xlrd   

# Define the location of the file   
loc = ("C:\\Users\User\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx")   

# To open the Workbook   
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)   
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)   

# For row 0 and column 0   
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
```

My Excel sheet

[image: Book1.xlsx]

Expected Output

```
Name
```

But Output is

```
>Python excel_001.py

>
```

Program executes without any error

Comment: Do you want to do `print(sheet.cell_value(0, 0))` to see the value in cell 0,0?

Comment: Yes I want to see the name of the first column. In the output of this program (i.e. Name) @VorsprungdurchTechnik

Comment: The line `sheet.cell_value(0, 0)` has no effect what so ever. As suggested you probably want to wrap that in a `print(...)`

Comment: I see I didn't print(sheet.cell_value(0,0)). I was doing this for the time. It is a silly question. Can I delete this question? . Will I be prohibited from asking question again. If I do that? @VorsprungdurchTechnik Thanks for your help. It means a lot to me.

Comment: @kenthompson: you're welcome. I don't think anything like deleting a question can prohibit you from asking a question again.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try to read the excel sheet as Pandas dataframe in python

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\User\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx")
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not printing it. I added a print statement

```
# Import the xlrd module    
import xlrd   

# Define the location of the file   
loc = ("C:\\Users\User\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx")   

# To open the Workbook   
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)   
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)   

# For row 0 and column 0   
print(sheet.cell_value(0, 0))
```

Comment: I see, I thought you were using Jupyter Notebook where you don't need the print function at the last executable line of a cell